# error 404 defining URL in mod rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to rewrite my URL's to be more clean and user friendly and also better for SEO, so whenever the user clicks each country link to see the list of train journeys for each country, i.e: Italy, it should call the page **country.php?country=italy** , but the URL should be rewritten to **great_train_journeys/country/italy**.

I've tried to set rewrite rules on a .htaccess file but i'm getting the 404 error.

Here is my code for the **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^country=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^country/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ country.php?country=$1 [NC,R]
```

I'm using XAMPP to work on my local server, so my project folder is inside the HTDOCS folder, which is the root of my server:

Here is my project structure:

[image: htdocs]

[image: project folder]

I've checked if mod_rewrite is enabled in the http.config file and also changed the AllowOverride to all like it is below:

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: comment on your RE: `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)*` has a `*` that should absolutely not be there. You're trying to capture "one or more ascii letters" (sort of), not "one or more letters. zero or more times"

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i also tried without the * before but forgot to take it out from my question. It is not working yet.

Comment: Always a possible silly question, but: is mod_rewrite actually enabled in the httpd.conf? Also, is your `.htaccess` file in the right directory for `^count` to properly apply?

Comment: mod_rewrite was already enabled. The .htaccess file is at htdocs. The i have the project folder "Trains" which contain the file country.php.

Comment: next question: what is the actual URL involved? Because if the htaccess file is in htdocs, then you might have forgotten to add `trains` to your rewrite rule

Comment: This is the actual URL: <a href='/Great_Train_Journeys/country/<?php echo $row_Countries['country_name'] ?>'><?php echo htmlentities (mb_convert_encoding($row_Countries['country_name', 'UTF-8', 'ASCII')); ?></a></li> Unfortunately i had to restart my project on another machine and didn't backup the .htaccess i was using before. I'm shure this was the actual URL i coded before and it was working well.

Comment: I tried to add the folder Trains to my rewrite rule but doesn't work yet: RewriteRule ^/Trains/country/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /Trains/country.php?country=$1 [NC,R=301]

Comment: Can you clarify what you need? Please edit your question and describe exact your situation (folder structure , etc.) and what you try to archive and where you stuck... and what you did so far.

Comment: @FabMon that is HTML code, not the actual URL: check what the link is that *the browser* sees, because that's what is going to get called on your server.

Comment: Mike sorry, misunderstood your question: the URL in the browser is localhost/Great_Train_Journeys/country/italy. I've edited my question, i hope it is better clarified. And the project name is actually great_train_journeys not just Trains.

Comment: I just needed to put the .htaccess inside the project folder and that was it. The code was correct. Anyway, i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to rewrite my URL's from this, country.php?country=Italy to this country/Italy

I believe you meant it the other way around, at least this is what your Code tells me. So if someone enter example.com/country/italy you want that the internally the this /country.php?country=italy is called but the user should not see it.

So in this case you need:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?country/([^/]+)/?$ /country.php?country=$1 [NC,L]
```

But if you mean it the other way around so that the URL in the browser is `example.com/country.php?country=Italy` but this should internally go to `example.com/country/Italy` than you need the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?country=([^&]*)(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^/country\.php$ /country/%2 [NC,L]
```

With this we have some small problems because if `example.com/country/Italy` is the real folder and someone enter `example.com/country.php?country=italy` that we will not find the folder with the name **italy** and we get a 404 error.

In your original Code you also used the [R] Flag (that means redirect), for exapmle if a user enters `example.com/country.php?country=italy` that the URL in the browser will change to `example.com/country/italy`
than you should do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?country=([^&]*)(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^/country\.php?$ /country/%2 [NC,R=301]
```

Now we do a 301 redirect.

Comment: thanks for the help. Yes, i want to change the URL request for the country.php page and respective country to a more clean URL hence my Rewrite Rule. I've tried your first bit of code but i still have the same 404 error. This was working well before, when i was developing on another machine. I have checked if mod_rewrite is enabled in the http.config file and if AllowOverride All is set and everything is fine. Dunno if i should look elsewhere.

Comment: Dose the folder e.g. /country/Italy exist or should this be redirectet to some index.php?

Comment: It doesn't exist. My website structure is this: Under the folder HTDOCS of XAMPP, which is the root of the server, i have the Trains folder where all my project files are...then inside i have several pages like index.php, country.php, contact.php etc. By the way, i might have caused some confusion while using the "R" flag but it was my mistake since it wasn't needed.